# How to implement DateTimeAxis control template in System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

Tags: wpf, charts

I want to override the default template but i have trouble implementing it.

I tried this:

```
<charting:Chart Title="{Binding Title}" Name="chChart" LegendStyle="{StaticResource LegendStyle1}">
    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:DateTimeAxis
                                x:Name="Abcisa"
                                Orientation="X"
                                ShowGridLines="True"
                                Title="{Binding Abscissa}">
            <charting:DateTimeAxis.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:DateTimeAxis}">
                    <Grid x:Name="AxisGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--generate content for x axis-->

                        <datavis:Title x:Name="AxisTitle" Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </charting:DateTimeAxis.Template>
</charting:Chart>
```

But i got this for visual tree:

[image: charting toolkit]

What should i do to create template for `DateTimeAxis` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Style` property of the `Title` to the `TitleStyle` of the `Axis`. This is what the default template looks like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:DateTimeAxis">
    <Grid x:Name="AxisGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <datavis:Title x:Name="AxisTitle" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But you also need to add some data series to the chart for the axis to show up. Please refer to the following article for more information about this and an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co